# logging my application's classes at DEBUG level, all others at WARN

Tags: grails, logging, log4j

I've configured my Grails app to read the log4j config from `/conf/log4j.properties` file instead of the more usual DSL in `Config.groovy`, by adding the following Spring bean:

```
log4jConfigurer(MethodInvokingFactoryBean) {
    targetClass = "org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer"
    targetMethod = "initLogging"
    arguments = ["/conf/log4j.properties", 1000 * 60] // 2nd arg is refresh interval in ms
}
```

My goal is to log all the classes in the app itself at the DEBUG level, and all others at the WARN level. `/conf/log4j.properties` contains the following:

```
log4j.logger.com.myapp=DEBUG, CONSOLE
log4j.logger.grails.app=DEBUG, CONSOLE

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p myapp %c{3} %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %t : %m%n
```

It seems the namespace `com.myapp` is used for regular classes in my app (e.g. those under `src/groovy`), whereas the namespace `grails.app` is used for Grails artefacts (controllers, services, taglibs, etc.). However the `grails.app` namespace also includes artefacts from plugins, which I don't want to log at the DEBUG level.

Is there a way to enable DEBUG logging only for the classes in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following solved the problem

```
log4j.logger.grails.app.conf.com.myapp=DEBUG, CONSOLE
log4j.logger.grails.app.filters.com.myapp=DEBUG, CONSOLE
log4j.logger.grails.app.taglib.com.myapp=DEBUG, CONSOLE
log4j.logger.grails.app.services.com.myapp=DEBUG, CONSOLE
log4j.logger.grails.app.controllers.com.myapp=DEBUG, CONSOLE
log4j.logger.grails.app.domain.com.myapp=DEBUG, CONSOLE
```

Presumably if a Grails app has other types of artefacts that you want to log at the DEBUG level, an additional logger should be configured for each one.

Answer (score 2):

You append your package unto the grails.app.controllers to get just your application.

```
info 'grails.app.controllers.mypackage'
```